# How to change DefaultSessionTrackingModes when HttpsSession is created

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jakarta-ee, httpsession

I want to change DefaultSessionTrackingModes when any HttpSession is created on basis of Login User

So for that, I have created my own HttpSessionListner

```
@WebListener
public class HttpSession1TrackingModeSetter implements HttpSessionListener
{

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener#sessionCreated(javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent)
     */
    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(final HttpSessionEvent hse)
    {
        hse.getSession().getServletContext().getDefaultSessionTrackingModes();
        System.out.println("Session is created" + hse.getSession().getId());
        if(/*Curr*/){
            // Default Session URL
        }else{
            // Defualt Session Cookie
        }

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed(javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent)
     */
    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(final HttpSessionEvent hse)
    {
        System.out.println("sessionDestroyed is created" + hse.getSession().getId());

    }



}
```

So is there any way to change the Default Session Tracking Mode

Thanks in advance,
Vishal

Comment: try to give a look here https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/java-servlet/session-tracking-mode.html

Comment: Hi @Angelo, Thanks for your reply but already tested this example I want to change the session tracking mode when any session will create i.e depends which user is login

Comment: You can use `ServletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(Set<SessionTrackingMode> sessionTrackingModes) ` to change SessionTrackingMode of servlet (means the change affects to all requests to that servlet). You can not change SessionTrackingMode for each request/user. Please see:  https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setSessionTrackingModes-java.util.Set-

Comment: Hi @Ken2009, Thanks for your valuable reply. So my question is it possible we detached the current ServletContextListner and Add new one in the application context for this depend on HttpsSession?

Answer (score 0):

Because comment can not explain details. Let me answer here:

> 1. So is there any way to change the Default Session Tracking Mode

Yes. Use `ServletContext.setSessionTrackingModes(Set<SessionTrackingMode> sessionTrackingModes)` to change SessionTrackingMode of servlet (means the change affects to all requests to that servlet).
You can not change SessionTrackingMode for each request/user.
Reference: [setSessionTrackingModes](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setSessionTrackingModes-java.util.Set-)

> 2. is it possible we detached the current ServletContextListner and Add new one in the application context for this depend on HttpsSession

First, i think you can NOT do that. Because the root of problem is you are trying to change application's scope property `sessionTracking`. This change affects for all requests in the ServletContext, not for some specific requests.
Second, you can use apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) to "change" sessionTracking for specific request.
- Add some header for specific request, what you want to change sessionTrackingMode. For example: 'X-SESSION-TRACKING-URL'
- In apache config, add a rule like that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-SESSION-TRACKING-URL} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.+) $1?jsessionid=%{HTTP_COOKIE:jsessionid}
```

Explanation:
%{HTTP:X-SESSION-TRACKING-URL} !^$: if there is header X-SESSION-TRACKING-URL, then do rewrite url
$1: all of url
%{HTTP_COOKIE:jsessionid}: get jsessionid from cookie, and set to url